# Displaying YouTube videos using MediaElement.js 2.9.1 in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, youtube, mediaelement.js

I’ve installed the plugin via wordpress and the audio player works fine but I’m trying to use [MediaElement](http://mediaelementjs.com) to display youtube videos. I’m using the following code to no avail:

```
video autoplay="false" src="http://http://youtu.be/GXxfAygoVLM" type="video/youtube" width="500" height="275"
```

The version I’ve installed is version 2.9.1.

Can you please advise where I’m going wrong and whether I need to add something to ‘mediaelement-js-wp.php’?

Edit: This is the current shortcode on the site (which doesn't work):

```
[video autoplay="true" src="http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXxfAygoVLM" type="video/youtube" width="500" height="275"]
```

Comment: Do you need Jetpack for this maybe? I can't get it to work either... not even with the embed url.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know about MediaElement.js 2.9.1 in Wordpress, but your link isn't pointing to video (It's not link to video file itself, but to html page)

Try direct link, you can get them with help of any download tool for youtube (I can't give you any because they are very long).

[maybe this way](http://r7---sn-gvnuxaxjvh-n8vz.c.youtube.com/videoplayback?cp=U0hVRVNTV19IUENONV9LTUFCOmJOZlBMTjFzUXZT&mt=1360365912&newshard=yes&key=yt1&id=00ca59d131a36d61&expire=1360389136&ratebypass=yes&source=youtube&ipbits=8&ip=195.69.191.203&sver=3&fexp=914040,916613,920704,912806,902000,922403,922405,929901,913605,925710,929114,920201,930101,911116,910221,901451,919114&mv=m&sparams=cp,id,ip,ipbits,itag,ratebypass,source,upn,expire&ms=au&upn=2A9H-XUQw84&itag=18&signature=6F913AF10CCBA631E37B0422E851357794E70FFA.25E49B685E2A00752DBCB9BF106FF27354D8BC2B&title=Official%20Ram%20Trucks%20Super%20Bowl%20Commercial%20Farmer)

Answer (score -1):

Well, the most obvious thing I can see is that you're including **http://** twice in your src attribute. Try removing one of them.

If that doesn't do the trick you might want to take it a step further. I've ran into this problem before with other Wordpress/ Youtube integrations when using a "youtu.be" link versus the actual "youtube.com" link.

Try changing: http://youtu.be/GXxfAygoVLM

To:
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GXxfAygoVLM

and see if that works for you.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I made changes after adding the problem to stackoverflow so I corrected the two http but unfortunately, it still didn't work. I've also use the full URL instead of http://youtu.be/GXxfAygoVLM and I'm still getting a black square with a download link.